# Submit button not working when inserting form value

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

controller: Purchase.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Purchase extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->model('purchase_data');
    }
    public function add_product_master()
    {
        if($this->input->post('submit'))
        {
            $data = array(
                        'product_name'=> $this->input->post('product_name'),
                        'category'=> $this->input->post('category'),
                        'sub_category'=> $this->input->post('sub_category'),
                        'description'=> $this->input->post('description'),
                        );
            $query = $this->db->insert('product_master',$data); 
            if($query == true)
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<p style="color: green;font-weight: bold;">Your product added successfully.</p>');
                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1'>";
            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<p style="color: red;font-weight: bold;">Error!</p>');
            }
        }
        $this->load->view('product-master');
    }
}
```

view: product-master.php

```
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message');?>
<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="product_name" id="product_name" required="required" />
  <input type="text" name="category" id="category" required="required" />
  <input type="text" name="sub_category" id="sub_category" required="required" />
  <textarea name="description" id="description" required="required"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="submit">
</form>
```

I have created a form having name product-master.php. But when I click on submit button it does't inserting form value or does't  showing any flashdata message don't know why. So, How can I fix this problem ? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: you need to add action to form tag.
<form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('purchase/add_product_master');?>">

Comment: are you receiving any error or something?

Comment: add action method in form tag @omkara

Comment: no I am not receiving any error @NaimMalek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in this line. you need to add `action` when form is `submit`

```
 <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" method="post"
 action="<?php echo site_url('purchase/add_product_master');?>">
```

use this code in this function `add_product_master` at the start of this function

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($this->input->post());
exit;
```

Comment: replace above line with your code and clear browser cache then submit form

Comment: what happen when you click on submit button?

Comment: when click on submit button it show nothing like flashdata or not inserting form value

Comment: @omkara i have update my answer try this and show result

Answer (score 0):

you need to add action method to form tag.

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('purchase/add_product_master');?>">
```

Comment: have you add action method? submit button are work when action method is applied

Comment: *submit button are work when action method is applied* is wrong statement. If request to be sent on same url/page then `action` is not required.

Comment: @B.Desai thanks for correction. 

try changing  if($this->input->post('submit')) to if (!empty($_POST))

Answer (score 0):

the action attribute is missing in your form, So you should add action attribute while adding form to your document.

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" method="post" action="URL">
```